# Unable to access form data on serverside

Tags: javascript, express, xmlhttprequest

I am making a put request from frontend for which I have been using `XMLHttpRequest and FormData` API request but server side I would not get any data like `req.params, req.body and req.query` all are empty

#### Front-end Code

```
var reportSub = () => {

        var report = document.getElementById('report');

        var formData = new FormData(report)



    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            console.log(xhr.response)
        }
    }

    var queryString = new URLSearchParams(formData);

    xhr.open("PUT", '/threads/edit', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    xhr.send(queryString)

}
 var reportsub = document.querySelector('#repsub');
 reportsub.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
        e.preventDefault();

        reportSub();
    })
```

#### Server Side code

```
router.put('/threads/edit',(req,res)=>{

    let board = req.body.board;
    let id = req.body.id;

    console.log(req.query,req.body)

    Board.findById({_id: ObjectId(id)},(error,data)=>{

      if(error)
          res.send(error)

      if(data!==null){
        data.Reprot = true;
        data.save((error,sd)=>{

          if(error)
              res.send(error)

           res.send(sd);   
        })
      } 
      else{
        res.send({"Error":"Id does not exist "})
      }   
    })
})
```

There is one solution would be where you add data in url which again hard coded each in every variable and data you had to pass.
So thats I want use FormData interface for sending data.

Comment: You can directly send the FormData using `.send`. Try using `xhr.send(formData)`. Only `req.body` should contain the required data. `URLSearchParams` cannot be constructed from `FormData`but could also be used to achieve this:

Comment: I already tried it would give me ```empty object```

Comment: Is `#report` a form element?

Comment: yeah. I think here something to do with request header

Comment: Are you using any middlewares to parse the request like `express.json()`?

Comment: Yes I do is there anything wrong with that

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a library for parsing the FormData request. You could also send the data using JSON as it is text-only, this would simplify parsing. A minimal example could look like the following:

`server.js`

```js
const express = require("express");
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer();
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'))

app.post('/data', upload.none(), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.favoriteNumber);
    res.send('42 is the only real choice');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('App listening on port 3000!');
});
```

`public/index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="textForm">
        <p>Your favorite number:</p>
        <input type="text" value="42" name="favoriteNumber" />
    </form>
    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <script>
        const sendButton = document.getElementById("send");
        const form = document.getElementById("textForm");
        sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                    console.log(xhr.response);
                }
            }

            const formData = new FormData(form);
            xhr.open("POST", '/data', true);
            xhr.send(formData);
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You do not have to set the header manually. It is set automatically and does include `boundary` - a parameter you cannot know while writing the application. The header could look like the following:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryuzeaYvzY77jzcFeA
```